# Deploy WPF on target Machine with .net FM 2

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworks

i made a simple WPF application with just 1 button to display a messagebox , i made that application on Visual Studio 2010 [.Net framework 3] and i tried to deploy that application on win 7 [No framework is installed just the the copy of windows and .net framework 2 is integrated] and win xp with .net framework 2 so i tested that application in win xp and 7 with no .netframework 3 installed at all and the application worked perfectly with no problems at all , how strange is that ? or is there something which i dont know ... could you please justify that thing to me and thanks a lot in advance .. love u stackoverflow ....

Comment: I think windows 7 is integrated with 3.5 .Net Frameworks ?

Comment: so does win xp ? i don`t think so man

Comment: have you read my answer below, it resolves exactly your question I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't strange at all. Windows 7 comes with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. If you targeted .NET 3.0 on XP and it worked, then the XP machine must of had .NET 3.0 installed.